# Select name of two foreign keys referring to same primary key table

Tags: sql, hana

I have an inventory transaction table `Transaction_Log`

The columns are `log_id`, `to_warehouse`, `from_warehouse`, both FOREIGN KEYs referencing to the warehouse table `OWHS` with columns `whs_id`, `whs_name`

I need to output with these columns: `log_id`, `to_warehouse_name`, `from_warehouse_name`

Tried this

```
SELECT t.log_id, w1.whs_name AS to_warehouse_name, w2.whs_name from_warehouse_name
FROM OWHS w1, OWHS w2
 INNER JOIN Transaction_Log t ON w1.whs_id = t.to_warehouse AND w2.whs_id = t.from_warehouse
```

but it throws an error

> invalid table name: w1.whs_id

I'm not sure whether the query is correct to output what I want, but the error already throws me off.

I use SAP HANA database, but I changed the column names a bit for this post. I'm also returning to database programming after several years, so I apologize if this is a basic question, but my googling returns nothing close to what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Period.  Write the query as:

```
SELECT t.log_id, w1.whs_name AS to_warehouse_name, w2.whs_name from_warehouse_name
FROM OWHS w1 JOIN
     Transaction_Log t
     ON w1.whs_id = t.to_warehouse JOIN
     OWHS w2
     ON w2.whs_id = t.from_warehouse;
```

Although you *could* also fix the problem by replacing the `,` with `CROSS APPLY` that just confuses the logic.  You are looking for two simple `JOIN`s.